# NSString to float value incorrect

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSString converting to a float value and the result logged is this

```
2,146.952 as a float is 2.000000
```

The comma seems to cause the float value to be rounded down, if I use doubleValue] it does the same.

Is there a way to get this to be `2146.952`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

1) Remove the comma from the string as

```
NSString * str = [str stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
```

2) Retrieve the float value from the string as

```
float f = [str floatValue];
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use a NSNumberFormatter.
if the format is always as show (source: Server api), set the decimalSeparator to `.` and the groutingSeparator to `,`.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];

NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:numberString];
```

if the string format depends somehow on the user preferences (input via keyboard), set the locale instead

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:numberString];
```

the second solution can also used for the first case, if you set a locale like

```
[numberFormatter setLocale: [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
```